# Issues with AJAX request and response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code to make requests for information from the server and display the response:

```
var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechanged=function(){
    if(ajax.readyState==4){
        if(ajax.status==200){
            window.alert(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
}
ajax.open("GET",url,true);
ajax.send(null);
```

I have executed the code in the debugger and validated the `url` is correct, which in my test is just `example.html`. There are 2 problems I can see:

1. When I log the HTTP headers, only about 25% of the time do I see a request for the page
2. When a response is sent back, it is always a 304 status code (although I imagine I just need to turn off caching for that file), but also, the `onreadystate` method is never called, for any of the `readyState`s

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** Number 2 is figured out, I disabled caching and changed `onreadystate` to `onreadystatechanged`. But number 1 is still occuring.